# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_curl.dll

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am having trouble getting cURL working on one of my servers. I have others set up exactly like this and they are working. Here is the error message in the system log:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

I've been researching this all day and nothing has worked. Here's the current state of the server:

- php.ini is in C:\php\
- php_curl.dll is in C:\php\ext\
- libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are in C:\php\
- extension=php_curl.dll is uncommented in php.ini
- Environment variable PATH = %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C\php;C:\php\ext;C:\Apache24\bin
- phpinfo() shows that C:\php\php.ini is the config file being used
- php.ini extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
- Apache is from [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/binaries/httpd-2.4.10-win32-VC11.zip)
- PHP is from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.2-Win32-VC11-x86.zip)
- OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

I've restarted several times. Other extensions are loading from the extension directory. I've also tried re-downloading the PHP zip file and replacing C:\php with the contents of the freshly downloaded zip file. I had this problem on a different server a while back when I was updating PHP and Apache. Replacing C:\php with a new copy of the zip file did fix it, but it is not helping now.

I will be happy to provide any additional information you may need.

Thanks.

---

phpinfo() configure command

`cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"`.

Comment: does phpinfo() show that curl is enabled?  Look for `cURL support enabled` you might need to recompile php with curl support... assuming you compiled yourself, maybe post your config.nice / config cmd

Comment: phpinfo() only mentions curl under the module authors section. I did not compile PHP myself. I downloaded the zip of VC11 x86 Thread Safe from windows.php.net/download - it has always worked in the past. phpinfo() has a configure command at the top. I'm not sure if that will be of help, but I posted it above.

Comment: well something must be different, i'd double check the package you're getting; if you have one of your past servers compare the phpinfo()

Comment: I tried to copy C:\php from the old server to the new one and it still didn't work. Both top sections (system, build date, compiler, architecture, configure command, etc.) of phpinfo() are identical between the two servers. The old one does show that curl is enabled.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mr.Squidward, so what was the solution of your problem?

Comment: There was a typo in the system PATH environment variable.`C:\php` was missing the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, "C\php" in PATH was missing a colon. Changed it to "C:\php" and it works now. I had a feeling it would turn out to be something like this... Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 7.3:

1. extension=php_curl
2. copy **libssh2.dll** from `C:\php` into `C:\apache\bin`
3. copy **libcrypto-*.dll** and **libssl-*.dll** from `C:\php` into `C:\apache\bin` (if it doesn't exist)

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Just make sure `C:\php` is added to the system PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Mr.Squidward this doesn't work for me, only in apache dir

Comment: This worked for me when I updated from PHP 7.3.8 to 7.4.0
Setting the PATH environment variable did not work for me (although that solved the same probelem I had with the intl extension)

Answer (score 3):

### In PHP 7.4:

It's a problem related to `Windows`, if you are using `Apache2.x` + `Php`, the trick consists in using `LoadFile` to force the loading of `CURL` as explained in my [Guide](https://gist.github.com/alecos71/de26b0079b963a690e798375b8561dfa). You don't need strange things or rituals to have `CURL` working on your machine, you only need edit `httpd.conf` and add this:

```
# load CURL library on Windows
LoadFile "${SRVROOT}/php/libssh2.dll"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have faced similar problem in our Environment.

We uninstalled Apache and installed it again with following commands:

```
c:\Apache\bin httpd -k uninstall 
c:\Apache\bin httpd -k install
```

and magic.... The problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll'

correct answer should workable as environment path for c:\php is missed . so just add

In Control Panel -> Search -> Advanced System Settings and use the button Environment Variables.

Under System Variables find Path add the c:\php folder (or whatever path) and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was taking another curl.exe file that was in the PATH before the one in C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score -5):

also you need to change the curl.dll version, you must overwrite the version that comes with wamp server. C:/wamp/bin/php/ext.

You can download the right version from this link

http://**www.mediafire.com/download/3ay381k3cq59cm2/php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip**

I hope it works for you!

font:
**http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716,85932**

Comment: cURL is here: http://curl.haxx.se/ I wouldn't trust the package on Mediafire (which may be uploaded by anyone).